How to connect visualVM over ssh to jmx started with `Jcmd ManagementAgent.start`
I try to attach visualVM to a running java process started without JMX flags(I don't have control over the startup script). To-do so, I enabled jmx with jcmd:
~> jcmd 15868 ManagementAgent.start  jmxremote.port=45678 jmxremote.host=127.0.0.1 jmxremote.authenticate=false jmxremote.ssl=false jmxremote.rmi.port=45678
~> jcmd 15868 ManagementAgent.status
15868:
Agent: enabled

Connection Type: local
Protocol       : rmi
Host           : 127.0.0.1
URL            : service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/stub/rO0ABXNyAC5qYXZheC5tYW5hZ2VtZW50LnJlbW90ZS5ybWkuUk1JU2VydmVySW1wbF9TdHViAAAAAAAAAAICAAB4cgAaamF2YS5ybWkuc2VydmVyLlJlbW90ZVN0dWLp/tzJi+FlGgIAAHhyABxqYXZhLnJtaS5zZXJ2ZXIuUmVtb3RlT2JqZWN002G0kQxhMx4DAAB4cHc3AAtVbmljYXN0UmVmMgAADDE5Mi4xNjguMC4yMwAAr09xSTzUAt4Xp2VIWiAAAAGTZAPJAYBBAHg=
Properties     :
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port = 45678
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.host = 127.0.0.1
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate = false
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth = false [default]
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl = false
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl = false [default]
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only = true [default]
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file = jmxremote.password [default]
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file = jmxremote.access [default]
  com.sun.management.config.file = management.properties [default]
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.port = 45678

Connection Type: remote
Protocol       : rmi
Host           : 127.0.0.1
URL            : service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1:/stub/rO0ABXNyAC5qYXZheC5tYW5hZ2VtZW50LnJlbW90ZS5ybWkuUk1JU2VydmVySW1wbF9TdHViAAAAAAAAAAICAAB4cgAaamF2YS5ybWkuc2VydmVyLlJlbW90ZVN0dWLp/tzJi+FlGgIAAHhyABxqYXZhLnJtaS5zZXJ2ZXIuUmVtb3RlT2JqZWN002G0kQxhMx4DAAB4cHc3AAtVbmljYXN0UmVmMgAADDE5Mi4xNjguMC4yMwAAsm7Lu/nHDfBys2VIWiAAAAGTZAPJAYBDAHg=
Properties     :
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port = 45678
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.host = 127.0.0.1
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate = false
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth = false [default]
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl = false
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl = false [default]
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only = true [default]
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file = jmxremote.password [default]
  com.sun.management.jmxremote.access

but I can't find any way to force jmxremote.local.only to false
After opening an ssh tunnel with:
ssh HOSTNAME -L 45678:localhost:45678
When startin visualvm(version 2.1.10) with visualvm --openjmx localhost:45678
I always end up with a:
Caused: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.0.23; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

How can you open JMX via JCMD to be accessible remotely?
